Install gettext library, always loaded
enter image description hereWhen I use vcpkg to configure the project, when installing
gettext has been loading for more than one night. How can I solve this problem?
I reinstalled vcpkg, reacquired my project, and rebuilt it, but it still keeps loading.

Please learn [ask], take the [tour], and maybe provide a [mre]. As it stands, no one can help you because you've not provided any actionable information. Is vcpkg in your PATH? Is it a submodule? Did you install the package via vcpkg install, or are you using a manifest file? How are you building your program? Are you using a build system? If so, which one? Are you using an IDE? If so, which one? It's up to you to provide enough information for someone that isn't you and doesn't have access to your machine to actually help.

What makes you think gettext is "loading?" Why don't you think you wrote an infinite loop? etc.

I did’t write any code ，I just build  my project using vcpkg

when I try  use vcpkg   ，vcpkg install gettext，It is loading all night

I see you edited in a picture of text. Please [edit] text into your question as text. My followup question is, is your computer pretty weak?
